# Grab date from html form

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a form with one of the inputs that is of type datetime-local. This form is eventually uploaded via angular.  What I am trying to do is convert the local date input to utc before posting it. I can't seem how to figure this out.  I've tried several ways, but I keep getting undefined values. here is what I tried:

HTML:

```
<input type="datetime-local" ng-model="PublishStartDate"
                                   name="PublishStartDate" class="form-control"
                                   id="publishStartDateId" />
```

JavaScript:

```
var formElement = document.getElementById('articleForm');
formElement.elements['PublishStartDate'].value = moment.utc(formElement.elements['PublishStartDate'].value);
var objData = new FormData(formElement);
```

I eventually post the form with this angular code below, as I am also sending file data as well:

```
$http.post('/api/ArticleAdminApi/UpdateArticle', objData, {
        transformRequest: angular.identity,
        headers: { 'Content-Type': undefined }
    })
```

Comment: why you are using pure javascript to get the date value from your model ?

Comment: why you are using pure javascript to get the date value from your model ?

Answer (score 0):

```
  <script>
    var app = angular.module('app',[]);
  </script>

<input type="datetime-local" ng-model="PublishStartDate"
                               name="PublishStartDate" class="form-control"
                               id="publishStartDateId" />
{{PublishStartDate}}
```

Look through the Plunkr : [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/ESzLgiK6sqFiXTcPiENK?p=preview)